# How to create virtual card in android programmatically?

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

I want to create a virtual card for android, and I have an android activity with following fields:

1) My name
2) Address
3) Contact Number
4) Receiver's email

I want to email this info to another android receiver in such a way that if that user clicks on it, it should give them an option to add this info to his contacts/phone book.

I have searched on Google but all I get is how to "how to create virtual SD card" and nothing else.

Please note its a programming related question.